# Codeceptjs doesn't load most elements, waitForNavigation() just causes it to freeze forever

Tags: automated-tests, codeceptjs

I am having an issue testing with codeceptjs. I am attempting testing apps on the Atlassian cloud but codeceptjs/puppeteer cannot interact with any of the elements on the page. When I enable screenshots I see it is on the right page but codeceptjs can only find the elements in the navigation menu. it cannot even find the body element either by selector or xpath. 
I tried adding `I.waitForNavigation()` but the tests never advance past that step. I tried to set a timeout in the config section as they say in the docs [here](https://docs.w3cub.com/codeceptjs/helpers/puppeteer/) but I am having no luck. I tried everything they suggested but it just waits there forever. if I comment out `I.waitForNavigation()` it will fail because it cannot find a Boyd element.  I am using the default config file that gets created when you install codeceptjs in a directory. this the code I am trying to test but it is causing all kinds of issues.

```
I.amOnPage('https://artemis-test2.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/ac/com.nurago.confluence.plugins.treecopy/copy-page-tree-confluence?page.id=25821196&space.key=TEST1');

I.waitForNavigation();
// if I don't comment this out it will wait here forever
I.wait(4);
I.waitForElement('.ap-iframe');
// it can find the iframe for some reason but nothing else
I.waitForElement('.body');
// if I do comment it out it fails here because it says there is no body element. can't find it by xpath either.
```

I have no idea why this is happening. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`amOnPage` with default config runs navigation and passes after navigation.

`waitForNavigation` will start to wait navigation after navigation. So it never happens, if you will not run navigation again or page redirect starts.

You have 2 choices:

1. not to use `waitForNavigation` and use `amOnPage` only.
2. use `waitForNavigation` and `amOnPage` within `Promise.all`: `await Promise.all(I.waitForNavigation(); I.amOnPage(pageUrl));`